# can not generate phoenix app

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

i want try Phoenix framework, but can not take it
I install elixir `brew install elixir`, after it, i install Phoenix `mix archive.install /path/to/archive` 
and try `mix phoenix.new new_app` and get the error:

`** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function:crypto.strong_rand_bytes/1 (module :crypto is not available)
    :crypto.strong_rand_bytes(64)
    lib/phoenix_new.ex:459: Mix.Tasks.Phoenix.New.random_string/1
    lib/phoenix_new.ex:187: Mix.Tasks.Phoenix.New.run/4
    (mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:55: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2`

Elixir -v 1.1.1

mix -v 1.1.1

erlang/OTP 18

OSX 10.11.1

Comment: this is probably related to openssl. i'd check if that is installed and then reinstall erlang and elixir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erlang was installed with brew, but was unlinked.

`brew link erlang` solve my trouble

Answer (score 0):

Try running this:

```
$ mix deps.get 
$ mix deps.compile
```

It may be that the crypto module didn't get pulled down. Either way the output of those commands may help you to get a better idea of what the issue is.

Comment: i think he's one step before that. if it already fails during `mix phoenix.new new_app` there's no project to fetch and compile deps in.

Comment: That's a good point. But it sure looks like a missing dependency error.