# can not generate phoenix project with new command

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've trouble like there [can't generate phoenix new app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040778/can-not-generate-phoenix-app)

but solutions that i discovered over there not actually for me because i'm using ubuntu 15.10
The propblem:
I tried to create new phoenix project via

```
mix phoenix.new my_app
```

command and catch follow error:

and was catch follow error

```
[error] Process #PID<0.47.0> raised an exception
(UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function:
:crypto.strong_rand_bytes/1 (module :crypto is not available)
:crypto.strong_rand_bytes(64)
lib/phoenix_new.ex:460: Mix.Tasks.Phoenix.New.random_string/1
lib/phoenix_new.ex:189: Mix.Tasks.Phoenix.New.run/4
(mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:60: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
(elixir) src/elixir_compiler.erl:126:
:elixir_compiler.dispatch_loaded/6
(elixir) src/elixir_lexical.erl:16: :elixir_lexical.run/3
(elixir) src/elixir_compiler.erl:30: :elixir_compiler.quoted/3
(elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
```

I'm have tried install erlang by two ways

1. I'm compile Erlang from source, then install Elixir and Phoenix
   framework from their sites instruction. It work fine. But i can't
   create a new phoenix project - error above.
2. I'm delete previous Erlang version and install Erlang from Ubuntu
   Software Center - Erlag works fine. But i can't create a project
   again for similar error

P.S mix works correctly for me. iex too.
Any suggestions?

Comment: the `phoenix` tag is for the Hadoop Phoenix, not the Elixir Phoenix

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have `crypto` installed which is very common when installing Erlang via kerl. There is no warning that the installation isn't fully functional. To confirm that, try this:

```
erl
1> application:start(crypto).
ok
```

If you get anything else than `ok` atom, try running this:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libncurses5-dev openssl libssl-dev fop xsltproc unixodbc-dev
```

And then reinstall Erlang.

It is possible that you have never needed `crypto` and worked without it, but when running `mix phoenix.new` it generates secret key for your application and it really needs that module.